# EXECUTE IMMEDIATE: Bind variable doesn't exist & Inconsistent Datatypes

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor

That's the block:

```
DECLARE CURSOR Cursore IS
    SELECT DISTINCT CONF.SCHEMA, CONF.TABELLA, CONF.CAMPO, CONF.TIPO_CAMPO, CONF.LUNG_CAMPO, CONF.CAMPO_ACCESSO 
    FROM EDWH.EDWH_GDPR_CONFIG CONF
    WHERE UPPER(FLAG_CANC) = 'Y'
    AND TABELLA = 'DWH_SIC_ANAGRAFICA_TEST'
    ORDER BY CONF.TABELLA, CONF.CAMPO;    

C_SCHEMA EDWH_GDPR_CONFIG.SCHEMA%TYPE; 
C_TABELLA EDWH_GDPR_CONFIG.TABELLA%TYPE;
C_CAMPO EDWH_GDPR_CONFIG.CAMPO%TYPE;
C_TIPO_CAMPO EDWH_GDPR_CONFIG.TIPO_CAMPO%TYPE;
C_LUNG_CAMPO EDWH_GDPR_CONFIG.LUNG_CAMPO%TYPE;  
C_CAMPO_ACCESSO EDWH_GDPR_CONFIG.CAMPO_ACCESSO%TYPE;   

COMPARA_CHAR VARCHAR2(32);
COMPARA_VARCHAR VARCHAR2(32);
COMPARA_NUMBER VARCHAR2(32);

update_block VARCHAR2(1000);

BEGIN   

COMPARA_CHAR := 'CHAR';
COMPARA_VARCHAR := 'VARCHAR2';
COMPARA_NUMBER := 'NUMBER';

OPEN Cursore;
LOOP
    FETCH Cursore INTO C_SCHEMA, C_TABELLA, C_CAMPO, C_TIPO_CAMPO, C_LUNG_CAMPO, C_CAMPO_ACCESSO;

        update_block := 'UPDATE ' ||C_TABELLA||' SET '||C_CAMPO||' = 
        CASE 
            WHEN '''||C_TIPO_CAMPO||''' = '''||COMPARA_VARCHAR||''' AND '||C_LUNG_CAMPO||' < 4 THEN ''XX''
            WHEN '''||C_TIPO_CAMPO||''' = '''||COMPARA_VARCHAR||''' AND '||C_LUNG_CAMPO||' > 4 THEN ''GDPR''
            WHEN '''||C_TIPO_CAMPO||''' = '''||COMPARA_CHAR||''' AND '||C_LUNG_CAMPO||' < 4 THEN ''XX''
            WHEN '''||C_TIPO_CAMPO||''' = '''||COMPARA_CHAR||''' AND '||C_LUNG_CAMPO||' >= 4 THEN ''GDPR''
            WHEN '''||C_TIPO_CAMPO||''' = '''||COMPARA_NUMBER||''' THEN ''0''
            ELSE (SELECT '||C_CAMPO||' FROM '||C_TABELLA||' WHERE '||C_CAMPO_ACCESSO||' = 199701360) 
        END
        WHERE '||C_CAMPO_ACCESSO||' = 199701360'; 

    --dbms_output.put_line (update_block);  

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE update_block USING C_TABELLA, C_CAMPO, C_TIPO_CAMPO, C_LUNG_CAMPO, C_CAMPO_ACCESSO, COMPARA_VARCHAR, COMPARA_CHAR, COMPARA_NUMBER; 

    EXIT WHEN Cursore%notfound;
END LOOP; 
CLOSE Cursore; 
END;
```

That's what i get from the commented dbms_output.put_line:

```
   UPDATE DWH_SIC_ANAGRAFICA_TEST SET NUM_ISCRIZIONE_CCIAA = 
        CASE 
            WHEN 'NUMBER' = 'VARCHAR2' AND 22 < 4 THEN 'XX'
            WHEN 'NUMBER' = 'VARCHAR2' AND 22 > 4 THEN 'GDPR'
            WHEN 'NUMBER' = 'CHAR' AND 22 < 4 THEN 'XX'
            WHEN 'NUMBER' = 'CHAR' AND 22 >= 4 THEN 'GDPR'
            WHEN 'NUMBER' = 'NUMBER' THEN 'xxxx'
            ELSE (SELECT NUM_ISCRIZIONE_CCIAA FROM DWH_SIC_ANAGRAFICA_TEST WHERE NDG = 199701360) 
        END
        WHERE NDG = 199701360
```

This update right here doesn't work at all. Can't figure out why... 
The error that i get is: ora-00932 inconsistent datatypes expected char got number
which seems like a clear error but i can't find the right solution to solve it. :/

Following the structure of the table DWH_SIC_ANAGRAFICA_TEST

```
 CREATE TABLE "EDWH"."DWH_SIC_ANAGRAFICA_TEST" 
 (  
 "COD_BANCA" VARCHAR2(4 CHAR), 
 "DATA_RIFERIMENTO" DATE, 
 "NDG" NUMBER(9,0), 
 "COD_OPERAZIONE" VARCHAR2(18 CHAR), 
 "COD_ABI" VARCHAR2(5 CHAR), 
 "COD_FILIALE" VARCHAR2(5 CHAR), 
 "COD_LEGAME" VARCHAR2(1 CHAR), 
 "NDG_SOCIETA" NUMBER(9,0), 
 "COD_LEGAME_SOCIETA" VARCHAR2(1 CHAR), 
 "COD_TIPO_FINANZIATO_GARANTE" VARCHAR2(1 CHAR), 
 "COD_FISCALE" VARCHAR2(16 CHAR), 
 "FLG_COD_FISCALE_CALCOLATO" VARCHAR2(1 CHAR), 
 "PARTITA_IVA" VARCHAR2(11 CHAR), 
 "RAGIONE_SOCIALE" VARCHAR2(120 CHAR), 
 "RAGIONE_SOCIALE_DITTA_INDIV" VARCHAR2(60 CHAR), 
 "COGNOME_ACQUISITO" VARCHAR2(25 CHAR), 
 "DESC_COMUNE_NASCITA" VARCHAR2(32 CHAR), 
 "DATA_NASCITA" DATE, 
 "SESSO" VARCHAR2(1 CHAR), 
 "COD_TIPO_SOCIETA" VARCHAR2(4 CHAR), 
 "COD_PROV_ISCRIZIONE_CCIAA" VARCHAR2(2 CHAR), 
 "NUM_ISCRIZIONE_CCIAA" NUMBER(7,0), 
 "FLG_CESSATA_ATTIVITA" VARCHAR2(1 CHAR), 
 "COD_PROV_REGISTRO_SOC_TRIB" VARCHAR2(3 CHAR), 
 "NUM_REGISTRO_SOC_TRIB" NUMBER(7,0), 
 "NUM_ISCRIZ_ALBO_IMPRESE_ART" NUMBER(7,0), 
 "COD_RAE" VARCHAR2(3 CHAR), 
 "COD_SAE" VARCHAR2(3 CHAR), 
 "COD_SOTTOCLASSIF_ATTIVITA" NUMBER(3,0), 
 "INDIRIZZO_RESIDENZA" VARCHAR2(40 CHAR), 
 "CAP_RESIDENZA" VARCHAR2(5 CHAR), 
 "DESC_COMUNE_RESIDENZA" VARCHAR2(30 CHAR), 
 "COD_PROV_RESIDENZA" VARCHAR2(2 CHAR), 
 "COD_NAZIONE_RESIDENZA" VARCHAR2(3 CHAR), 
 "NUM_TEL_RESIDENZA" VARCHAR2(16 CHAR), 
 "INDIRIZZO_DOMICILIO" VARCHAR2(40 CHAR), 
 "CAP_DOMICILIO" VARCHAR2(5 CHAR), 
 "DESC_COMUNE_DOMICILIO" VARCHAR2(30 CHAR), 
 "COD_PROV_DOMICILIO" VARCHAR2(2 CHAR), 
 "COD_NAZIONE_DOMICILIO" VARCHAR2(3 CHAR), 
 "NUM_TEL_DOMICILIO" VARCHAR2(16 CHAR), 
 "FLG_ANAG_NUOVA_VARIATA" VARCHAR2(1 CHAR), 
 "COD_ATECO" VARCHAR2(8 CHAR), 
 "ANNO_RIF_COD_ATECO" NUMBER(4,0), 
 "DATA_CONTABILE" DATE, 
 "DATA_ESTRAZIONE" DATE, 
 "DATA_INSERIMENTO" DATE, 
 "DATA_ULTIMO_AGGIORNAMENTO" DATE
 )
```

Comment: What is the structure of table: `DWH_SIC_ANAGRAFICA_TEST`? Please share it on question

Comment: Also your execute immediate has using keyword but there are no bind variables in your query. Bind variables are used directly within string following ` :` colon. Like `:bindvariable`. So in your block directly execute the string using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE update_block;`

Comment: Your  `NUM_ISCRIZIONE_CCIAA`  column is as `NUMBER(7,0)` data type and update statement will try to set 'xxxx' value for this column. which in result failing and throuwing `ora-00932.` error

Comment: I've uploaded the structure of the table. Sorry to ask you again, but how should i use the bindvariable in my situation?

Comment: If you just remove the single quotes around `''0''` in your `update_block` (to `0`), that should fix it.

Comment: Where is the `'xxxx'` which is printed in the UPDATE statement coming from? Based on the code it looks to me like this should be `'0'`. ????

Comment: @kfinity: automatic data conversion should convert the `'0'` to a numeric value of 0, but in the DBMS_OUTPUT results it's being printed as `'xxxx'`. [db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=65c1b74383cacc5730e353f6b6203e6e)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with your code:

- you are not using bind variable in `update_block` and still you are using `using` block. You should remove `using` block from `execute immediate`.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE update_block;
```

- `NUM_ISCRIZIONE_CCIAA` column is of `number` type and you are trying to update it using `case when` with all `varchar2` type while your else block is generating `number` again which inconsistent. `Case when` must produce same data type result.

For more details on bind variables, see [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/improve-sql-query-performance-by-using-bind-variables).

Cheers!!

Comment: Oh - you're right, the problem is actually the ELSE section - it's selecting a number which doesn't match the other cases. If they try `ELSE to_char('||C_CAMPO||') END` I think that should work.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I finally solved the problem. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

You don't use any bind variables, it should be similar to this one (quick and dirty):

```
    update_block := 'UPDATE ' ||C_TABELLA||' SET '||C_CAMPO||' = 
    CASE 
        WHEN :C_TIPO_CAMPO = :COMPARA_VARCHAR AND :C_LUNG_CAMPO < 4 THEN :XX
        WHEN :C_TIPO_CAMPO = :COMPARA_VARCHAR AND :C_LUNG_CAMPO > 4 THEN :GDPR
        WHEN :C_TIPO_CAMPO = :COMPARA_CHAR AND :C_LUNG_CAMPO < 4 THEN :XX
        WHEN :C_TIPO_CAMPO = :COMPARA_CHAR AND :C_LUNG_CAMPO >= 4 THEN :GDPR
        WHEN :C_TIPO_CAMPO = :COMPARA_NUMBER THEN 0
        ELSE (SELECT '||C_CAMPO||' FROM '||C_TABELLA||' WHERE '||C_CAMPO_ACCESSO||' = 199701360) 
    END
    WHERE '||C_CAMPO_ACCESSO||' = 199701360'; 

--dbms_output.put_line (update_block);  

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE update_block USING 
   C_TABELLA, C_CAMPO, C_TIPO_CAMPO, C_LUNG_CAMPO, C_CAMPO_ACCESSO, COMPARA_VARCHAR, COMPARA_CHAR, COMPARA_NUMBER,
  'XX','GDPR','XX','GDPR';
```